# Post data to a django view using ajax is not working

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a view and i want to post data using ajax method but it is not entering the view to print content.

My javascript code:

```
$("#id").click(aa);
var aa= function() {
var id= $("#id");

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/id",
    method: "POST",
    data: { user: id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },
    context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {

    alert("Success");

}).fail(function(returnedText) {
    console.log(returnedText.responseText);
});
```

};

My Django view:

```
def id(request):
    print("aa");
    users = request.POST['user']
```

My URL:

```
path('/ajax/id', views.id, name='id')
```

Comment: Are you getting success or failure ?  If failure, what's the error response ?

Comment: @Dhirendra it is not calling the view at all

Comment: but you should be getting some response either in `done` or `fail` function.  Which function is being called ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request header instead

```
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');

(($) => {
  const csrfSafeMethod = method => /^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method);
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.method) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
      }
    },
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

And the error is the url use `url: "/ajax/id",` instead of url: "ajax/id", and accessing the POST dict directly the `id` is also builtin function try renaming your function to not overshadow builtins.

```
users = request.POST.get('user')
```

And you path doesn't